# Draw Rectangle in JFrame not working

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have this bit of code that's supposed to draw a rectangle on a `JFrame` but when I run the program on Eclipse, it just opens the frame, but does not draw the circle on it.

Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Infout {
    Infout(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setSize(300, 400);
        frame.setTitle("An Empty Frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Infout m = new Infout();
         m.paint(null); 
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
         g.drawRect(5, 5, 105, 105);
    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me why it's not working properly?

Comment: Where do you call the paint method

Comment: [Refer this link]


   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713432/drawing-simple-rectangles-on-a-jframe-in-java

Comment: +1 For posting your question with a valid SSCCE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking to do is call `frame.repaint();` instead. This still doesn't sort your problem however, because your `paint()` method isn't actually Overriding the `JFrame`'s `paint()` method because your class does not extend `JFrame`, it is just creating a `JFrame` in the constructor.

So, you can *either* do a last minute override and move your paint method into that (as per polypiel's answer), or (I personally think more eloquently) you can have your class extend JFrame, like so;

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Infout extends JFrame{
    Infout(){
        setSize(300, 400);
        setTitle("An Empty Frame");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Infout m = new Infout();
         m.repaint(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
         g.drawRect(5, 5, 105, 105);
    }

}
```

As other's have pointed out however `paintComponent()` is a better choice of override, and you should remember to make an appropriate call to `super()` at the beginning of the new overridden method. You will have to then create a new `JPanel` to put inside your `JFrame` because `JFrame` does not have a `paintComponent()` method to override.

To do this you could remove your `paint()` method from your class entirely and add the following last minute override into your constructor:

```
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(new JPanel(){
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawRect(5, 5, 105, 105);
        }
    }, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

For extensibility and good object orientated design however, you may be better off in the long term defining your own `JPanel` subclass and overriding the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method there. Sorry for waffling, I hope this helps.

Comment: Custom painting need to be executed in `paintComponent()` of `JComponent` with calling `super()` method.

Comment: @alex2410 - One problem at a time, they OP needs to understand what they did wrong and why their current code doesn't work first. I will edit my answer to suggest that paintComponent() is a better choice of override.

Comment: If OP doesn't ask about this, you need to suggest him to use better way for avoiding problems in the future.

Comment: Add an example with paintComponent and I' ll give you up vote.

Comment: @alex2410 - Appropriate code example of `paintComponent(Graphics)` added : )

Answer (score 2):

You have managed to completely break the paint chain by calling:

```
m.paint(null);
```

It should be:

```
m.repaint();
```

As a result of a call to `repaint()`, the `paint(Graphics)` method will be called automatically, but with a **valid** graphics object.

Note that it is typically considered better to override the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method of a `JPanel` that is added to a `JFrame` (or a window, or an applet, or a dialog..).

The thing to do when overriding either method, is to call the super method before doing anything else.

Answer (score 1):

The should overwrite the paint method of the `JFrame`. A paint method in `Infout` is useless.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Infout {
    Infout(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame() {
          @Override public void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.drawRect(5, 5, 105, 105);
          }
        };

        frame.setSize(300, 400);
        frame.setTitle("An Empty Frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Infout m = new Infout();
         // You shouldn't need to call repaint
    }
}
```

Comment: *"`frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);`"*  Don't use magic numbers when there are defined constants.

Comment: That's why the @Override annotation is useful

Comment: Custom painting need to be executed in `paintComponent()` of `JComponent` with calling `super()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call the paint externally and call the super.paint in your paint() method.

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
 super.paint(g);
//....

}
```

and remove m.paint(null).

Comment: Custom painting need to be executed in `paintComponent()` of `JComponent` with calling `super()` method.